# DRF: Updating a model in another models serializer or view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

so I have a User and schools model which are related as an Owens(ManyToMany), student, and staff, if an owner registers and creates a school, I would like to perform a partial update to the Owens field of the request.user from having a null/blank or previously created schools to adding the newly created school

user model

```
 class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    
        class SEX(models.TextChoices):
            ...
    
        class TYPES(models.TextChoices):
            ...
    
        ...
        owens = models.ManyToManyField(School, verbose_name=_(
            "School_owner"), related_name='Schoolowner', blank=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class SchoolSerializerBase(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

class Meta:
    model = School
    fields = ...

def validate(self, attrs):
     ...
    return attrs

def create(self, validated_data):
    instance = School.objects.create(
        ...
    )
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

and i have a simple view for it

```
class CreateSchoolView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = School.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsSchoolOwner, ]
    serializer_class = SchoolSerializerBase
```

**My question:** how do I update the request.user.ownes field and add the school instance to it??

Comment: What is ownes field ? could you add your models ?

Comment: i edited it in, basically the Owens field refers to the school model, it tells who owns the school, many people could own one school and 1 user can own many schools

Comment: Consider to use Django signals (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain that result by overriding .create() in your serializer

In your serializer

```py
def create(self, validated_data):
   instance = super().create(validated_data) # this is the school
   # you then create the entry for your User+School
   # example
   user = self.context['request'].user
   user.owens.add(instance)
   return instance
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/relations/

Comment: error ``ModelSerializer.create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'``

Comment: do i do ``School.objects.create in the super().create()`` or just pass in the ``validated_data`` the later is what i did

Comment: Where does name come from ? I've update the function. the .create() function of the modelserializer doesnt need any change to create the school instance. we override it in order to add the ManyToMany entry only.

Comment: this worked but I was tryna save each fields like ``name=validated_data['name'],`` is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do. Where are you trying to do it and what is the final objective you want to accomplish by doing that ?

Comment: save selected fields from the school model not all at once

Comment: Ok but why ? If you want to restrict the choice of your user when creating a school, you already have "fields" attr. of your serializer for that. If not, it looks like it will take another s/o question with full explanation of what you try to do because it will be beyond the scope of what we can properly achieve in the comment section